# Updating an array and save the result PHP

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array in php, for example:

`$room = array("wall", "blank");`

this array is in a file on my own host, how can i update this array by adding new values and save the result? so the next time when i open the file I'll see the updated array? or this is impossible?

p.s this is my first post, sorry if i made a mistake

Comment: Well to start with, show us at least an example of the file you have on disk, and how you currently read this file and make it into an PHP array. Give us a bit of a clue

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) as was suggested to you to do when you registered
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the new value to the array function on the creation of the array.

```
$room = array("wall","blank","newValue");
```

You can add a new value after the array is created.

```
$room = array("wall","blank:);
$room[] = "newValue";
```

You can use array_push() function to insert it at the end of the array.

```
$room = array("wall","blank");
array_push($room,"newValue");
```

You you can use array_unshift() function to insert it at the beginning of the array.

```
$room = array("wall","blank");
array_unshift($room,"newValue");
```